# Maximum file size supported by WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-esb

I've a **IBM filenet** document upload API, which has to be exposed in **WSO2 API Manager**. What is the **Maximum** file size that API Manager can handle?

Answer (score 1):

WSO2 API Manager does not place any restrictions on the size of the data being sent out of the box.

Comment: Can we share 5 gb data transferred in a single API request?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Keep in mind though that your network infrastructure needs to support transferring files of this size so that it does not exceed the timeout limit configured for a given API request to last. This is something you will need to evaluate on your infrastructure.